# how to create an empty virtual machine without os in kvm?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Can any one help me to create virtual machine in kvm hypervisor without os. Just the vm should have 8GB disk, 512 MB RAM and default NIC interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create an empty image which will be used by the virtual machine to store data as:

```
qemu-img create vm_no_os 8G
```

Here, an 8GB disk is created of type raw with name `vm_no_os`.

Next, use this image as the hard-disk for the virtual machine and boot the virtual machine without any OS:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -hda vm_no_os -name vm -net nic
```

Here, you can replace `qemu-system-x86_64` with `qemu-system-i386` if you are using a 32-bit system.

`-m 512` represents using 512 MB of RAM

`-name vm` represents a name given to the VM being created

`-net nic` creates a new Network Interface Card for the VM.

Refer [manual page of qemu-system-x86_64](http://man.cx/qemu-system-x86_64%281%29) for more.

Comment: Thanks Jobin. It works for me. I've one more question. while creating virtual machine in oracle virtual box, the VM doesn't boots. Is there any possibility the same way in kvm also?

Comment: I am not sure if oracle virtualbox has an option to do this.

Comment: What I mean is in KVM it is booting after creation even the VM doesn't have OS, but in oracle virtualbox it just creates the empty vm but it wont boots. that's what i'm asking